# On the click of the image it is not removing in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Selecting the multiple image from the input tag after that I am previewing the selected image but when I click on that image it should delete from the input tag it does not select that picture any more. But in my case that picture is removing only in preview not in input. And save it into database

Here is the code

```php
    <?php
       include_once 'Functions.php';
       $connect=new Connection();
       $link=$connect->Connect();

       print_r($_FILES['fil']['name']);
    ?>

    <html>
       <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                var image=('')
                 ('input[type="file"]'). change(function(e){
                    var fileName = e. target. files[0]. name;
                    alert('The file "' + fileName + '" has been selected.' );
                  });

                  $(function() {
                     var imagesPreview = function(input,placeToInsertImagePreview) {

                     if (input.files) {
                        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

                        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                           var reader = new FileReader();
                           reader.onload = function(event) {
                           $($.parseHTML('<img class="picture" width="70" name="multipic">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                           $('.picture').click(function(){
                           $(this).remove();

                          });
                       }
                       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                    }
                 }
              };

              $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
                 imagesPreview(this,'div.gallery');
              });
           });
        });
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form name="update"  enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST">
          <input type="file" name="fil[]" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" class="a1">
          <div class="gallery"></div>
          <input type="submit" name="btnupdate" value="Update" />
        </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is **HTML Code** :

```
<div class="container">
     <form id="fileupload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="row files" id="files1">
             <h2>Files 1</h2>
             <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                 Browse  <input type="file" name="files1" multiple />
             </span><br/>
             <ul class="fileList"></ul>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <button type="x" id="uploadBtn" class="btn primary start">Start upload</button>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="span16">
                <table class="zebra-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is **CSS Code** :

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is **jQuery Code** :

```
$.fn.fileUploader = function (filesToUpload, sectionIdentifier) {
    var fileIdCounter = 0;

    this.closest(".files").change(function (evt) {
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
            fileIdCounter++;
            var file = evt.target.files[i];
            var fileId = sectionIdentifier + fileIdCounter;

            filesToUpload.push({
                id: fileId,
                file: file
            });

            var removeLink = "<a class=\"removeFile\" href=\"#\" data-fileid=\"" + fileId + "\">Remove</a>";

            output.push("<li><strong>", escape(file.name), "</strong> - ", file.size, " bytes. &nbsp; &nbsp; ", removeLink, "</li> ");
        };

        $(this).children(".fileList")
            .append(output.join(""));

        //reset the input to null - nice little chrome bug!
        evt.target.value = null;
    });

    $(this).on("click", ".removeFile", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var fileId = $(this).parent().children("a").data("fileid");

        // loop through the files array and check if the name of that file matches FileName
        // and get the index of the match
        for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
            if (filesToUpload[i].id === fileId)
                filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        }

        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    this.clear = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
            if (filesToUpload[i].id.indexOf(sectionIdentifier) >= 0)
                filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        }

        $(this).children(".fileList").empty();
    }

    return this;
};

(function () {
    var filesToUpload = [];

    var files1Uploader = $("#files1").fileUploader(filesToUpload, "files1");

    $("#uploadBtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0, len = filesToUpload.length; i < len; i++) {
            formData.append("files", filesToUpload[i].file);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("DONE");

                files1Uploader.clear();

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR - " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});

Try above code. Hope this will help
```

Comment: where i am removing the clicked image

Comment: try to give id name to form and then try

Comment: it is loosing all the image

Comment: I need only the preview one to savee into the database

Comment: Code only answers stink. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Hi! Please add an explanation to your answer as review has marked this as low-quality due to length and content and is at risk of being deleted by the system. Thanks!

Comment: Code is Updated.